# Wildfly Swarm JGroups YAML

Tags: jakarta-ee, yaml, microservices, jgroups, wildfly-swarm

I've downloaded the Wildfly swarm examples and now I am trying to move the configurations in Main classes to YAML files.

So far, everything is working, except the ribbon example. I took the configuration from the example project and tried to convert it into YAML file.

Project source: https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/blob/master/ribbon/events/src/main/java/org/wildfly/swarm/examples/netflix/ribbon/events/Main.java

My YAML file (as I think it should look like)

```
--- 
swarm:
  context:
    path: proxy
  http:
    port: 8080
  jgroups: 
    default-channel: swarm-jgroups
    stacks:
      udp:
        protocols:
          FD_SOCK:
            socket-binding: jgroups-udp-fd
          TCP:
            properties:
              bind_port:
                value: 9090
          TCPPING:
            properties:
              initial_hosts:
                value: "localhost[9090],localhost[9091],localhost[9092],localhost[9093]"
              num_initial_members:
                value: 4
              port_range:
                value: 4
              timeout:
                value: 3000
          FD_ALL: null
          VERIFY_SUSPECT: null
          pbcast.NAKACK2: null
          UNICAST3: null
          pbcast.STABLE: null
          pbcast.GMS: null
          UFC: null
          MFC: null
          FRAG2: null
          RSVP: null
        transports:
          UDP:
            socket-binding: jgroups-udp
```

But I am getting two Exceptions: On startup in the first line:

```
Error getting subresources for Stack java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to adopt value java.util.Map
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.EntityAdapter.fromEntity(EntityAdapter.java:347)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.Marshaller.appendNode(Marshaller.java:33)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.Marshaller.marshalSubresources(Marshaller.java:129)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.Marshaller.appendNode(Marshaller.java:38)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.Marshaller.marshalSubresources(Marshaller.java:129)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.Marshaller.appendNode(Marshaller.java:38)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:23)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.marshal.SubsystemMarshaller.marshal(SubsystemMarshaller.java:59)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.marshal.SubsystemMarshaller$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.marshal(Unknown Source)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.marshal.DMRMarshaller.marshal(DMRMarshaller.java:70)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.marshal.DMRMarshaller$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.marshal(Unknown Source)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeServer.start(RuntimeServer.java:182)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeServer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl.lambda$bootstrap$1(ServerBootstrapImpl.java:158)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.ClassLoading.withTCCL(ClassLoading.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl.bootstrap(ServerBootstrapImpl.java:113)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.start(Swarm.java:369)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:623)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:39)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:46)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:37) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.MapTypeAdapter.toDmr(MapTypeAdapter.java:22)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.config.runtime.invocation.EntityAdapter.fromEntity(EntityAdapter.java:341)
        ... 24 more
```

And then the jgroup sepcific exception:

```
    ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
    ("stack" => "udp")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCLJG0010: Transport for stack udp is not defined. Please specify both a transport and protocol list, either as optional parameters to add() or via batching."
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

Maybe you guys can give me a hint?

Comment: There were some issues discovered when we were doing the exact same change. I'm not up to date as to whether the example has been fixed to use YML yet. If not, it should be soon

Comment: I just saw that the Main class was moved to the project-defaults.yaml. I copied it from the git repository but I am still getting exceptions saying that the properties for TCP, TCPPING and GMS are undefined. Maybe its because I am using the 2017.6.1 release and not the 2017.7.0-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: That's possible, we should be releasing 2017.7.0 in the next few days

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the release 2017.7.0 fixed the problem and everything is now starting up correctly.

Thank you, Ken, for your quick response and support.